# Get new route page in $routeProvider resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

Having  -

```
.when('/nextPage.html', {
    templateUrl: 'src/app/views/nextPage.html',
    controller: 'myCtrl',
    resolve: function(/* args.. */) {
       console.log('Routing to page-'+/* the new page name */)
       // should log - "Routing to page-nextPage.html"
    }
})
```

I want to get the new page I will routing to it (`nextPage.html`) within the function in the `resolve:`  , how could I get it ?

Comment: Do you mean `location.href = "nextPage.html";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$route.current` to access the new route object.

```
resolve: {
    log: function($route) {
        console.log($route.current);
    }
}
```

Is you wanna get `templateURL` value it should be in `$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl`

Comment: I tried it but I get - `Object {}` in  `$route.current.params`

Comment: could you try `$route.current.loadedTemplateUrl` ?

Comment: that's weird, you may double check property name or log the whole `$route.current` object` and look whats inside